# php codes ruins shortcode structure

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to use shortcode in index.php but when I use PHP code in my shortcode, it displays out of shortcode structure.

this HTML code works

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode label="sample title" Description="Content Goes Here"]'); ?>
```

this code doesn't work and pushes PHP code out of short code structure

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode label="'. the_title() .'" Description="Content Goes Here"]'); ?>
```

it outputs like this:

```
sample title
<div class="hidden-content">
<span class="show-content"></span>
<div class="showme hidden" style="display: none;">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

But it must be like this

```
<div class="hidden-content">
<span class="showcontent">sample title</span>
<div class="showme hidden" style="display: none;">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `the_title()` to `get_the_title()`.

You are asking the shortcode to echo out a string that is returning the title.

It would be good for you to research the difference between `the_title` and `get_the_title`.

The main difference is that `the_title` is actually returning the title without any other requirement (this is simplified: there are filters happening as well) but it is why you see it first before the rest of the code.

Comment: you mean when working with shortcodes wee need to use get_the_title(). This interesting but works well I did not expect that how simple it was.

Comment: That's a generalization, but a good rule to follow.  Usually in creating shortcodes I add everything to a single variable and then return that variable which is how it is more often done, and in that case yes you need to use `get_` functions instead of functions that immediately return data (such as `the_`),